# How do I adjust touchpad scroll sensitivity in Wayland/Gnome?

Tags: gnome, wayland

Touchpad scrolling is extremely sensitive in Wayland/libinput. The touchpad controls in system settings are very limited. Does anyone know how to adjust this?

My thinkpad has a clickpad (the worst invention ever) and I'd also like to get two finger clicks working with it instead of the location and time dependent clicks that it currently has. Judging by the documentation for libinput, this may not happen.

Comment: Same issue here on the Macbook Air (2013 model) in Ubuntu 17.10 when using Wayland. When I use X, the scroll sensitivity is good.

Comment: Same issue here (Asus Zenbook), any updates?

Comment: The scroll sensitivity has been fixed in 17.10 on my thinkpad, but it has created another strange problem where waking from sleep only allows scrolling with 3 fingers. I will dig into this a bit more in the next couple of days to see if I can figure out how to configure this in the backend.

Comment: The most recent updates seem to have taken care of all my problems. Best of luck to you folks with MacBooks. I suggest filing a bug report on launchpad if it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to a terminal and type:

```
synclient PalmDetect=1
synclient HorizHysteresis=10 
synclient VertHysteresis=10
```

then keep adding zeroes to the following 2 parameters:

```
synclient HorizHysteresis=100
synclient VertHysteresis=100
```

until it becomes not responsive enough.  E.g.:

```
synclient HorizHysteresis=1000
synclient VertHysteresis=1000
```

Then halve that number and keep halving it until it's just right.  E.g.:

```
synclient HorizHysteresis=500
synclient VertHysteresis=500

synclient HorizHysteresis=250
synclient VertHysteresis=250
```

When that works, leave a comment with the value you have and I'll edit this answer to give you the perfect answer.  If it doesn't, I'll delete...

Comment: Even though updates fixed most of the problem, this did help me fine tune touchpad sensitivity. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is accepted but wrong. Wayland does not use the synaptics driver and executing synclient should tell you that there is no driver loaded.

Comment: @kjyv Post your own answer and ask the OP to change the acceptance...

Comment: I guess "you can't do it atm" is not a very useful answer. Just added my comment so people don't get confused by this not working.